# Angular Service worker (ngsw-worker.js) is not generated in the "/dist" folder after running build command

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm checking an NX project to see if the service worker is performing as planned. After running "ng build appname," I have a problem in that the Angular Service worker is not generated in the "/dist" folder. What can I do to fix this?

Imported in the app.module as should below

```
// PWA
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { 
  enabled:true,
  // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the app is stable
  // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
  registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
  // registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately' 
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by adding the following in the package.json.

```
script
{
"ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json",
"ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/",
"build-prod-ngsw": "ng build --prod && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy",
"serve-prod-ngsw": "npm run build-prod-ngsw && http-server dist -p 8080"
}
```

**"ngsw-config"**: This command uses the Angular Service Worker Configuration (ngsw-config) tool to generate a service worker configuration file using the configuration file provided in the
`src/ngsw-config.json` file, and stores the generated file in the `dist` folder. The tool is invoked using the command `node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config` and the output is written to the `dist` folder.

**ngsw-copy**: This command copies the generated service worker script "ngsw-worker.js" from the `@angular/service-worker` package in the `node_modules` folder to the `dist` folder using the `cp` command.

**build-prod-ngsw**: This command invokes the Angular CLI build command with the "--prod" flag to build the project in production mode. After the build completes, it invokes the `ngsw-config` and `ngsw-copy` commands defined earlier to generate the service worker configuration file and copy the service worker script to the `dist` folder.

**serve-prod-ngsw**: This command first invokes the `build-prod-ngsw` command to build the project and generate the service worker configuration and script. Then it starts a simple HTTP server using the `http-server` package with the root directory set to the `dist` folder and the port set to 8080. This allows the production-ready application to be served and accessed through a web browser at `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: How can you run these commands from the CLI?

Comment: @A.Casanova you can run from the cli by using **npm** or **yarn** e.g `npm run build-prod-ngsw` or `yarn run build-prod-ngsw`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `serviceWorker: true` flag set in angular.json for specific build.

For example, make sure you have
`projects.{project-name}.architect.build.options.serviceWorker` set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

service worker is enabled in prod mode only by default
you have to make a couple of changes

1-

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { 
  // you already set this config
  enabled: true,
}),
```

2- in angular.json move the option `serviceWorker` from `architect.build.configurations.production` to `architect.build.options`